# Include all rows where a value occurs, otherwise, remove

Tags: r

I have a dataset, df

```
Subject

Hi
hello
RE: Hello
RE: How is work
No
Ok
RE: What time are 
Hello RE: are you
FW: hello
```

I would like to include all rows where the first word is RE: and FW, excluding all others

```
Subject


RE: Hello
RE: How is work
RE: What time are 
FW: hello
```

Here is the dput:

```
 structure(list(Subject = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
 7L), .Label = c("hello", "HI", "No", "ok", "RE: Hello", "RE:   How     is work", 
 "RE: What time are", "FW: hello"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",       row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```

I am thinking to use grepl, but not sure how to formulate this.

```
subset(df, grepl('^RE', 'FW', Subject))
```

Comment: `subset(df, !grepl('^RE|^FW', Subject)) `

Comment: @Ronak I will re-word. I would like to keep all rows that contain RE and FW as the first row, and exclude all others

Comment: So `subset(df, grepl('^RE|^FW', Subject))` ?

Comment: yes thank you! This works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the pattern with `|`

```
subset(df, grepl('^(RE|FW)', Subject))
```

Or using `grep`

```
df[grep('^(RE|FW)', df$Subject), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak, Does this work if RE or FW is lower case as well? (re, fw)

Comment: No..but you can add `ignore.case =TRUE` in both grep and grepl.

Comment: Hi @Ronak it is giving error      subset(df, !grepl('^RE', ItemSubject) ignore.case = TRUE)        I am not sure where to add this

Comment: Use `subset(df, grepl('^(RE|FW)', Subject, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Comment: ok @Ronak, furthermore, if there are more than two conditions, can I do this:  subset(df, grepl('^(RE|FW|Fwd)', Subject, ignore.case = TRUE))

Comment: Yes it will select all the rows with `RE|FW|Fwd` in it.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(str_detect(Subject, '^(RE|FW)'))
#               Subject
#1             RE: Hello
#2 RE:   How     is work
#3     RE: What time are
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(df, startsWith(as.character(Subject), 
           "RE")|startsWith(as.character(Subject), "FW"))
```